# $\mathrm{End}_R(R[x])$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R[x],R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is $\mathrm{End}_R(R[x])$ (the set of all $R$-module homomorphism from $R[x]$ to $R[x]$) isomorphic to $R[x]$, for some ring $R$?

Also, Is $\mathrm{Hom}(R[x],R)$ (the set of all $R$-module homomorphism from $R[x]$ to $R$) isomorphic to $R$, for some ring $R$?

Comment: Isn’t the $R$-module $R[x]$ just a free module on countably many generators? This fact should allow you to answer your question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Below $R$ should be commutative or else it's quite unclear what is meant by $R[x]$.)

$R[x]$, as an $R$-module, is just the free $R$-module on countably many generators $\{ 1, x, x^2, ... \}$. That means $\text{End}_R(R[x])$ is the ring of infinite column-finite matrices over $R$, which is a bigger ring than $R[x]$, and $\text{Hom}(R[x], R)$ is $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} R$, which is again bigger than $R$.

However, it's true that the set of all $R$-*algebra* homomorphisms from $R[x]$ to $R$ is just $R$. Abstractly this means that $R[x]$ is the free $R$-algebra on one generator. It's also true that the endomorphism ring of $R[x]$ as an $R[x]$-module is $R[x]$. In both cases you need to explicitly remember more structure involving $R[x]$ as a ring.

Comment: I am looking for a ring R that is satisfying these isomorphisms in my question, but I couldn't find such a ring

Comment: If $R = \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{\aleph_0}$, then I there is an abelian group isomorphism $R^\mathbb{\aleph_0} \cong R$.

Comment: Is there a good reference for learning the properties of R[x]